# Why does `gem install` work but not `bundle install`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rvm, bundler, nokogiri

In my project when I ran `bundle install` I got the following error:

```
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So I did try

```
 gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'
```

This did work. Now of course this should make me happy, but I am wondering now, what exactly did the trick, so I could install the gem and now `bundle install` also succeeds.

I am running Mac OSX 10.9.2.

This is my Log when I first ran `bundle install`

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-xml2-dir=/usr --with-xslt-dir=/opt/local --with-iconv-dir=/opt/local
Extracting libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0/ports/libxml2/2.8.0... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Running 'install' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Activating libxml2 2.8.0 (from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0/libxml2/2.8.0)...
Extracting libxslt-1.1.26.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0/ports/libxslt/1.1.26... OK
Running 'configure' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Running 'compile' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Running 'install' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Activating libxslt 1.1.26 (from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0/libxslt/1.1.26)...
checking for libxml/parser.h... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin/ruby
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --with-iconv-dir
    --with-iconv-include
    --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
    --with-iconv-lib
    --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
    --with-xml2-dir
    --with-xml2-include
    --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
    --with-xml2-lib
    --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
    --with-xslt-dir
    --with-xslt-include
    --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
    --with-xslt-lib
    --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
    --with-libxslt-config
    --without-libxslt-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-libxml-2.0-config
    --without-libxml-2.0-config
    --with-libiconv-config
    --without-libiconv-config

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/1.9.1/nokogiri-1.6.1/gem_make.out
```

Comment: There's an error for missing dependencies. Have you tried looking at installing them? http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
brew install libxml2 libxslt libiconv
```

The reason you were not able to install it only by `bundle install` is because `bundler` only handles the gem dependencies and not local dependencies. The gem required your system to have `libxml2` which you did not have. So you needed to install them. The things which hints to my answer is this error message in your logs:

```
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. My question is more _why_  I could install the gem through `gem install` but not through `bundle install`.

Comment: But does `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'` install the required dependencies?

Comment: Not very sure.. the reason could be that `--include-dependencies` is a default option for `gem install`

Comment: You might be right with that assumption. Since it now installed successfully, it is tricky to figure out what the actual problem was.